# Как сформировать название колонок в DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Для столбцов 'p' и 's', я делаю pct_change()

```
predict_step = 10
trades = 30
```

Для 'p':

```
data['step_p'] = data['p'].shift(predict_step)
data['step-1_p'] = data['p'].shift(predict_step+1)
for i in range(1, trades+1):
    data[i] = data['step-1_p'].pct_change(i)
```

Для 's':

```
data['step_s'] = data['s'].shift(predict_step)
data['step-1_s'] = data['s'].shift(predict_step+1)
for i in range(1, trades+1):
    data[i] = data['step-1_s'].pct_change(i)
```

Как видите, у меня названия столбцов (`data[i]`) для 's' и 'p' совпадают и как следствие, 's' перекрывает 'p'.
Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы при генерации колонок по 's' и по 'p', названия колонок были уникальными? 
Например, для 'p':

```
'p_1', 'p_2', 'p_3' ... 'p_30'
```

Для 's':

```
's_1', 's_2', 's_3' ... 's_30'
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так:

```
for i in range(1, trades+1):
    data[f"p_{i}"] = data['step-1_p'].pct_change(i)
    data[f"s_{i}"] = data['step-1_s'].pct_change(i)
```